# How to get sql query from peewee?

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

Simple peewee example:
MySQL DB "Pet" with autoincrement "id" and char-field "name".

Doing

```
my_pet = Pet.select().where(name == 'Garfield')
```

With .sql() we get the sql interpretation.

How to get the raw sql query from:

```
my_pet = Pet.get(name='Garfield')
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write:

```
my_pet = Pet(name='Garfield')
```

Nothing at all happens in the database.

You have simply created an object. There is no magic, as peewee is an ActiveRecord ORM, and only saves when you call a method like `Model.save()` or `Model.create()`.

If you want the SQL for a query like `Model.create()`, then you should look into using `Model.insert()` instead:

```
insert_stmt = Pet.insert(name='Garfield')
sql = insert_stmt.sql()
new_obj_id = insert_stmt.execute()
```

The downside there is that you aren't returned a model instance, just the primary key.

Comment: Sorry, was a mistake from me. The line in question is "my_pet = Pet.get(name='Garfield')" Note the ".get". I edited the question

Comment: `.get()` does not return a query object, instead it returns a model instance, constructing and then discarding the query. It's roughly the same as `Pet.select().where(Pet.name == 'Garfield').limit(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to a Postgres database, per peewee `3.13` you can print SQL queries by first getting the cursor, then calling `mogrify()` for your query. Mogrify is provided by the `psycopg2` library and hence may not be available when connecting to other databases.

Given your example:

```py
my_pet = Pet.select().where(Pet.name == 'Garfield').limit(1)

cur = database.cursor()
print(cur.mogrify(*my_pet.sql()))
```

Where `database` is the Peewee Database object representing the connection to Postgres.

Comment: As I noted in GitHub - this may only work with psycopg2. The standard library sqlite3 module, for instance, does not support this API.

Comment: Thanks @coleifer - have updated the answer to reflect its specificity to pg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's "%" operator to build the string

```py
def peewee_sql_to_str(sql):
    return (sql[0] % tuple(sql[1]))

insert_stmt = Pet.insert(name='Garfield')
sql = insert_stmt.sql()

print(peewee_sql_to_str(sql))
```